# Android SDK Platform 24

Tags: android

I have a problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gakVV.png)

Gradle sync failed: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-24' in: C:\Users\Marcelina\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Consult IDE log for more details

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the link written in the error  (Click on Install missing platforms and sync project):

Or Open SDK Manager and Install SDK platform-tools 24